# How to broadcast and get notification using Express, AngularJS, Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to make notification system. To demonstrate this, User 1 is sending friend request to User 2. I am using express.js, angularjs and socket.io. On click of the button User1 sends request. On end of User2, there is a socket,on() which is listening on friend-request event. But when I am broadcasting, the other user is not able to receive any message.

**app.js** (Node Server File)

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));

require('./config')(app,io);
require('./routes')(app,io);
```

**config.js**

```
// This file handles the configuration of the app.
// It is required by app.js

var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app, io){

    // Set .html as the default template extension
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    // Initialize the ejs template engine
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

    // Tell express where it can find the templates
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    // Make the files in the public folder available to the world
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

};
```

**routes.js** (Emitting Friend Request From this File)

```
var gravatar = require('gravatar');
var mysql = require('mysql');
// This is needed if the app is run on heroku:
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "",
    database : "two_way_demo"
});

connection.connect(function(error){
    if(error)
    {
        console.log("Problem with MySQL"+error);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Connected with Database");
    }
});

module.exports = function(app,io){
    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.render('index');
    });

    app.get('/create', function(req,res){

        // Generate unique id for the room
        var id = Math.round((Math.random() * 1000000));

        // Redirect to the random room
        res.redirect('/chat/'+id);
    });

    app.get('/home/:id', function(req,res){

        // Render the chant.html view
        res.render('home');
    });

    // Initialize a new socket.io application, named 'chat'
    var chat = io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('get-user-id',function(data){

            connection.query("SELECT * from user_info WHERE email='"+data.userEmail+"'",function(err,rows){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
                }
                else
                {
                    //console.log(rows);
                    JSON.stringify(rows);
                    socket.emit('user-id',rows);
                }
            });
        });
        socket.on('send-request',function(data){
            console.log(data);
*********************************************************************
             // Tried the emit here but its not working
                //io.emit('friend request', {
                //    receiverid: data.receiverid
                //});
*********************************************************************
        });

    });
}
```

**angular-code.js** (angular code file)

```
$(function () {
    var app = angular.module("notificationApp", []);

    app.controller("chatCTRL", ["$scope", "$http", "$interval", function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
        // connect to the socket

        //var socket = io();
        //socket.on('connect', function () {
        //    io.on('friend request', function (data) {
        //        alert("here")
        //    });
        //});

        $scope.senderId = Number(window.location.pathname.match(/(\d+)$/)[1]);

        $scope.sendrequest = function (senderid, receiverid) {

            var socket = io();
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                socket.emit('send-request', {
                    senderid: senderid,
                    receiverid : receiverid
                });
            });
        }
    }]);

    app.controller("loginCTRL", ["$scope", "$http", "$interval", "$window", function ($scope, $http, $interval, $window) {
        $scope.sendLogin = function () {
            var socket = io();
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                socket.emit('get-user-id', {
                    userEmail: $scope.hisEmail
                });
            });
            socket.on('connect', function () {
                socket.on('user-id', function (data) {
                    $scope.UserId = data[0].user_id;
                    $window.location = "http://localhost:3000/home/" + $scope.UserId;
                });
            });
        }
    }]);
}());
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="notificationApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="chatCTRL">
<h1>welcome</h1>
    <div id="createbutton">
        <div id="little"><button ng-click="sendrequest(senderId,6)">Send Friend Request to User#6</button></div>
    </div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="../angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../angular/common_angular.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Nutty...hi i want to do friend request in my meanjs app....i have tried many ways and i have searched many links to find the exact solutions but it's not useful to us...so can you please help us ?...how can i wrote code to do a friend request in my app....please help us,,,thanks if you have plunker please provide to know the exact structure and solution as well.....revert back as soon as possible...thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Some client side architecture things:

1. In most cases on angular client side it is better to move your socket connection to service. And make connection when service is initialized (service is singleton, therefore there will be one connection on start) and inject this service in your controllers.
2. It may be convenient to create some parent abstract controller with
   all socket listeners, therefore whether angular controller is active, all listeners are watching. When parent controller get data from socket it can broadcast it to children controllers

In your commented code you have:

```
    //var socket = io();
    //socket.on('connect', function () {
    //    io.on('friend request', function (data) {
    //        alert("here")
    //    });
    //});
```

change it to this (if you make connection in service you should omit connect part):

```
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function () {
      socket.on('friend request', function (data) {
        alert("here")
      });
    });
```

### Backend:

In your commented code you have:

```
//io.emit('friend request', {
//    receiverid: data.receiverid
//});
```

You should use `socket`'s from `var chat = io.on('connection', function (socket) {...` to emit instead of `io.emit`

Create array variable where you will store all your sockets with users id before connection part:

```
var socketList = [];
var chat = io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socketList.push({id:someId,socket:socket})
  ...
}
```

Now in `send-request` user should send id of his frient (we have to know which user should be notified- of course we can notify everybody):

```
socket.on('send-request',function(data){
  socketList.forEach(function(soc){
    if(soc.id === someId){
      soc.socket.emit('friend request', {
        receiverid: data.receiverid
      })
    }
});
```

Also i don't like this part `receiverid: data.receiverid`, because it means that taget user get id of receiver from receiver client side. And this may be unsafe (user can change his id and send some other id). I prefere to create id in server side and when user A send notification to user B I get user A id from server variable.

Some time age I create simple prototype of chat application (angular and express), there are some things which I mention here. I you have still problems with your application go there and check my code :
https://github.com/uhlryk/chat-prototype

Comment: ...hi i want to do friend request in my meanjs app....i have tried many ways and i have searched many links to find the exact solutions but it's not useful to us...so can you please help us ?...how can i wrote code to do a friend request in my app....please help us,,,thanks if you have plunker please provide to know the exact structure and solution as well.....revert back as soon as possible...thanks.....

Comment: Hi. The Idea of stackoverflow is to share knowledge with broad audience. Im not sure if I can help you, maybe someone else. Please create separate question and very likely someone answer it. You can also paste link to this question below my comment and I will try to answer it.